# vim doesn't display first line?

Tags: vim, centos-5, less

when I use vim to open *some* php files, it starts with line 2, other files display fine. When I view the file with less I have the same issue. however when I edit it with nano I can see that line's in the file and my php works properly when I run it in browser. Like I said, it's only on some files others display the first line correctly.

ALSO if I use the right arrow key to move around some of the lines in the file will be replaced by the corresponding text in the previous line except the last character, again this isn't every line in the file, just some. It's very odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mismatch between the value of the environment variable TERM and the terminal-emulation mode of your console/ssh-client/telnet-client/terminal.

Comment: How do we find out what should `TERM` be set to?